# Parse.com data automatic update

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am developing a social network app that uses Parse.com as a back-end
I gave users the ability to change their name , email and profile picture (which is a parseFile)
And when users are logged in i gave them the ability to add posts
I add the posts by getting the user email and name by

```
ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
```

and saving the returned content to my ParseObject
but now the question is what if the user updated his data which is the profile picture or name or email how to update the post data dynamcly

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to write some cloud code.  https://parse.com/docs/js/guide

I would create an beforeSave trigger for your users, check to see if the relevant fields are 'dirty' (have been changed), and, if they have been, create a new object of a customer class that just has a pointer to that user.

Save a pointer to the user on each post.

Create a background job that runs each day/hour/however often you want to do these updates that goes through all of your custom objects that contains a user, use Query.each() to go through each of those objects, and then do a query for all posts where the user key is equal to the user of the custom object. Then set the name/email fields as appropriate.

Make sure that when you're done, you delete all of the custom objects so that you don't continuously perform this job on more and more objects each time.

Alternatively, you could just add the user pointer to the post, and when you fetch your posts, include the user key, so that gets fetched as well.  Then you can read the name/email directly from the user, which will always be dynamic.  You have to make sure that your ACLs are set up so that users can't edit all of another user's info or something, though.

Comment: Put doesnt cloud code need javascript while i am using androoid

Comment: Cloud code is written in javascript, yes, but it is accessed from any client.  

You don't want clients to have to receive too large amounts of data, i.e. every post a user has ever made.  That data has to be received, and sent back out when it's updated. It should be done on server side, not cloud code.  You call your cloud code functions from the android client. If you end up making an iOS version, you don't have to rewrite any cloud functions. You access the same ones.

Using cloud code will be the only proper way to do this.